# For loop logic runs but doesn't make sense

Tags: java, for-loop

> *VisitProcedure.length equals 7*

So for some reason this method works how I want it to. But the logic makes no sense to me. I have an array of *7* and i want the user to type in some part of the index *0-6* and it will display the value at that index. If they type in a number thats out of bounds then it throws an exception. But this is how i read the if statement logic

> if index is less then 0 or index is greater then 6 do this 
>   (p = VisitProcedure[index].getProcedure(); //displays the index

But instead it does the opposite. When i pick *0-6* It displays the value of the array at that index. And when i do anything else its out of index. Also when i try a different logic

> if index is greater then equal to 0 and less then 7 do this

I still run into error. But basically everything works fine it just doesnt make sense to me why.

```
public Procedure GetByIndex(int index)throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
            Procedure p;
            if (index < 0 || index > 1 - VisitProcedure.length) { //switching 1 - to - 1 still doesnt work
                p = VisitProcedure[index].getProcedure();
                return p;   
            }
            else{
                ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ar;
                ar = new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(); 
                throw ar;
                //throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

            }
        }
```

Comment: should be `index > VisitProcedure.length - 1` and you should switch the if and else blocks

Comment: But if you're throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException anyway, you don't really have to check the array bounds

Comment: Your logic is reversed here... If I pass down -1 as index, it will go inside the if statement.

Comment: If this code seems to work, then that probably means that you forgot to recompile after you changed working code to this non-working code.

Comment: like commented in the code `index > VisitProcedure.length - 1` will not work. The logic is still wrong no matter where the -1 or 1- is. But even though the logic is wrong if index = 0-6 it still goes into the if statement and if its any number above 7 it will go into the else statement. but like i stated that if statement shouldnt make the program work that way. yet it does. at least from my understanding

Comment: *have not forgot to recompile*

Comment: the condition should have been (index >= 0 && index <= VisitProcedure.length-1). On the how part, I'd suggest to go with Eclipse(or any other IDE of your choice) debuggers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is wrong, but it works anyway for the following reasons:

- if you pass a valid index (between 0 and 6), `index > 1 - VisitProcedure.length` is `true` (since `1 - VisitProcedure.length` is negative), so the if condition is `true` and you return `VisitProcedure[index].getProcedure()`.
- If you pass an invalid `index > 6` or `index < 0`, the condition is still `true`, and accessing an invalid index of the array throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (i.e. it is still thrown, but not by the `else` clause).

In other words, your condition is always `true`, so your code is equivalent to:

```
public Procedure GetByIndex(int index)throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    return VisitProcedure[index].getProcedure();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If(index>0 && index<=VisitProcedure.length-1){
    //if index is greater than 0 and less than or equal to index 6

    p = VisitProcedure[index].getProcedure();
            return p; 

}else{
 ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ar;
            ar = new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(); 
            throw ar;
            //throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

}
```

Comment: `If(index>0 && index<=VisitProcedure.length-1){` should be `if(index>=0 && index<VisitProcedure.length){` -- you're excluding zero as a valid index, but the OP has mentioned that 0-6 are valid indexes.

Comment: I dont need help in solving a correct logic for it. But i want to understand why this logic i am using now still give me the result i am looking for when it appears to be wrong